# pip install で "NewConnectionError"、"Failed to establish a new connection"、"名前解決に一時的に失敗しました"と出力される。

Tags: ubuntu, dns, pip

pip installのコマンドを打つと

```
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fcd53d9fe80>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] 名前解決に一時的に失敗しました',)':
```

というエラーが出力される。

調べてみると、pipの問題でなくネットワークの問題だということがわかりました。
ネットワークの問題の中でも、DNSの設定がうまくできていないと起こるようだったのでdns設定周りを調べて見たところ、特に問題はなさそうでした。
どなたか、解決方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃればご教授いただけると幸いです…

ちなみに、以下が私のdns周りの設定です。
$dns_server_addrにpingを飛ばすとしっかりレスポンスは返ってきます

/etc/nsswitch.conf

```
hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUNT=return] dns
```

/etc/network/interfaces

```
dns-nameservers $dns_server_addr
```

/etc/resolve.conf

```
nameserver $dns_server_addr
```

Comment: まず考えられるのがプロキシです。プロキシを使っていませんか？

Comment: Yasuhiro Nijiさん、コメントありがとうございます。学内のサーバであるためおそらく使用していると思うのですがどこにもプロキシを設定したような痕跡がありません。プロキシを使用しているかどうか確認するにはどのファイルを確認するべきなのでしょうか。

Comment: 回答の方に書いておきます。これで繋がらないのは珍しいです。

Comment: プロキシのアドレスを確認し、回答のように実行すれば無事pip installすることができました！ご教授いただき誠にありがとうございます！

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ptoxy経由でpipを使用しないといけない場合は、以下のように`proxy`オプションを付けて`pip`

を実行します。

```
pip install --proxy http://[user:password@]proxyserver:port package
```

または、環境変数`https_proxy`にproxy情報を設定後、`pip install`を実行するようにします。

```
export https_proxy="http://[user:password@]proxyserver:port"
```

なお、[]の部分は、proxyを使うのにパスワードが必要な場合で、必要がない場合は省略できます。

英語版の質問
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149422/using-pip-behind-a-proxy