# pipが全く動きません。

Tags: python, pip

Pythonを使ってみようとインストールしました。(Python2.7)でもってpipのバージョン確認(9.0.3)
まず手始めにnumpをインストールしようと`python -m pip install nump`としたところ、

```
Collecting numpy
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.conne
ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03386F10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.conne
ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03386790>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.conne
ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03387CB0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.conne
ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03387DB0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.conne
ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03386510>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/numpy/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for numpy
You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 18.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

と出てインストールできず、pipをバージョンアップしてみたいなメッセージがでているのでメッセージ通り
`Python -m pip install --upgrade pip`としたところ

```
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connect
ion.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03276BD0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/pip/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connect
ion.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03276CB0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/pip/
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connect
ion.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03276D10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/pip/
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connect
ion.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03276E10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/pip/
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connect
ion.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03276F10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/pip/
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\python27\lib\site-packages
You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 18.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

とでてアップグレードも出来ません。
ちなみに他のものをインストールを試みましたが上記の様なメッセージがでて出来ませんでした。
要するにpipが正常動作しません。
どうすれば動作するようになりますでしょうか。
（windows7)

Comment: 会社内などプロキシーサーバー経由で接続していませんか？
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44950994/python-m-pip-install-u-pip-errno-11004

Comment: どのように `pip` をインストールしましたか？

Comment: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/43671

Comment: 一旦Ｐｙｔｈｏｎを使うためのプログラムを全てアンインストールし再インストールしなをした所、動作しました。有難う御座いました。

Comment: @bee さん。コメントで解決する事は出来る限り避けていただくようお願いいたします。解決した内容については、自己回答を書き、**質問が投稿された時点より二日後**に、承認ボタンを押していただくよう、お願いいたします。